# Nashorn fails to execute MATH function

Tags: java, typeerror, nashorn

Am using Nashorn script engine in java for evaluating expressions,

the below code for `log` works,

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("noshorn");
engine.eval("Math.log(99);");
```

whereas for `log10` fails,

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("noshorn");
engine.eval("Math.log10(99);");
```

it throws an **exception** saying,

```
Caused by: <eval>:1 TypeError: Cannot call undefined
```

How can i resolve this.Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Math` that is initialized by default not the java system Math. If you want the java's Math use:

```
var JavaMath = Java.type("java.lang.Math");
```

Then you can use all of the math methods. I am surprised Nashorn doesn't provide the [javascript Math Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math), which would have log10.

Answer (score 1):

Nashorns [current](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/nashorn/file/tip/src/jdk/nashorn/internal/objects/NativeMath.java) Math implementation is based on this [version](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8.1) of the standard which does not yet contain `Math.log10`.

@matt has already given a workaround (+1), here is another one

```
engine.eval("java.lang.Math.log10(99);");
```

Answer (score 1):

Math.log10 is from ECMAScript6 -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log10 ,  http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-math.log10

Nashorn as of jdk8u implements ECMAScript 5.1. (few) Elements of ES6 being added to jdk9.